# Using JavaScript , how do I keep user input on page after it has reloaded?

Tags: javascript, html

I used HTML and JavaScript to allow a user to enter text and then push submit. When the user pushes submit, his text is displayed on the page. The problem is that when the page is reloaded, the text goes away. Obviously. Here is the code I have:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 
</head>
<body>
<p id="printhere"></p>
        <TEXTAREA Name="content" ROWS="5" COLS="20" id = "userInput"></TEXTAREA>

        <button  onclick="display()">post</button>
        
           
<script>function display(){


 var post = document.getElementById("userInput").value;

document.getElementById("printhere").innerHTML = post;
}</script>   
   


       
</body>
</html>
```

With JavaScript, is there anyway to make input stay once the page reloads?

Comment: When you press the reload button your browser request a fresh copy of the page. So the state of this page is completely lost. You can use localStorage to store your text(or whatever information you want to store). After the value stored in localStorage you can use the localStorage to retrieve the data and display it to your user(It will work if you refresh the page). For more information visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p id="printhere"></p>
<TEXTAREA Name="content" ROWS="5" COLS="20" id="userInput"></TEXTAREA>
<button  onclick="display()">post</button>  


<script>

    function display(){
        var post = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
        localStorage.setItem('userInputValue',post);
    }
    window.addEventListener('load',()=>{
        var savedUserData = localStorage.getItem('userInputValue');
        document.getElementById("printhere").innerHTML = savedUserData;
    });

</script>
```

## Edit for multiple input:

```
<p id="printhere"></p>
<TEXTAREA Name="content" ROWS="5" COLS="20" id="userInput"></TEXTAREA>
<button  onclick="display()">post</button>  


<script>

    var num = 0;
    function display(){
        var post = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
        localStorage.setItem(num,post);
        var savedUserData = localStorage.getItem(num);
        document.getElementById("printhere").innerHTML += savedUserData+'<br>';
        num++;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load',()=>{
        if (localStorage.length !== null) {
            for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
                var savedUserData = localStorage.getItem(i);
                document.getElementById("printhere").innerHTML += savedUserData+'<br>';
            }
        }

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Is there anyway to let the user do multiple input?

Comment: @Landon now you can do multiple input.

Comment: Thank you, but it is say null, null, null, and the multiple input won't stay up.

Comment: Its working, but it only lets me do three multiple input, an then it say null, null, null.

Comment: I am using chrome, if that helps.

Comment: It lets me do it, but when I put input in it sometimes replaces the lats input.

Comment: try to clear localstorage f12->application->localstorage->file:///->right click on mouse-> click on clear

Comment: in my browser it is working fine

#before page reload
[link](https://i.imgur.com/8i1Mnh6.png)

#after page reload
[link](https://i.imgur.com/96QlJgM.png)

Comment: That is really weird. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have f12. I have a chromebook.

Comment: try on firefox or other browser

Comment: OK. Thank you I'll check that.

Comment: No  I didn't get anything to work. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: I would like to say that I am only 13, so please give me some slack and don't make me answer some other people's questions!

Answer (score 0):

You can use storage APIs (sessionStorage, localStorage) to acheive the same. 
**Note**: Store only the data which is not sensitive. Never use it for sensitive data.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Example using sessionStorage: https://codepen.io/kishin-karra/pen/zYvgQZZ?editors=1010

sample code:

```
var savedPost = sessionStorage.getItem('text');
document.getElementById("printhere").innerHTML = savedPost;
document.getElementById("userInput").value = savedPost;
function display() {
    var post = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    document.getElementById("printhere").innerHTML = post;
    sessionStorage.setItem('text', post);
}
```

Enter the text, click post and refresh

Comment: So, how would I store it in a cookie?

Comment: @Landon dont use cookies, use localStorage because its easier to use.

Comment: added an example using sessionStorage. You can replace sessionStorage with localStorage. The example would still work

Answer (score 0):

Well, ideally this value should come from the server through an API.
However, if you're keen on doing it with JavaScript, you may consider `localstorage`

```
var post = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
localStorage.setItem("post", post);

document.getElementById("printhere").innerHTML = post || localStorage.getItem("post");
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use `preventDefault` like this:

```
function display(event){
event.preventDefault()

var post = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
document.getElementById("printhere").innerHTML = post;
}
```